# Ask-my JavaScript Not work ! Opencart

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, triggers, opencart

I have a form, i need to enable to textbox when my textbox is checked, and clear the value when the checkbox  not check. i'm using javascript and my Js not working ..

this is my form code

```
<?php if($this->config->get('config_dropshipper')){?>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2"><input type="checkbox" name="dropship" id="dropship" value="1"/>
        <label for="dropship" ><b>Beli sebagai dropshipper</b></label>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="highlight">
        <td>Dropshipper</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="dropshiper_name" id="dropshiper_name" value="<?=$dropshiper_name?>"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Nomot Telepon</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="dropshiper_phone_number" id="dropshiper_phone_number" value="<?=$dropshiper_phone_number?>" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<?php } ?>
```

My JS Code

```
$('#dropship').bind('change', function() {
    if ($('#dropship').prop('checked')) {
        $("#dropshiper_name").attr("disable", false);
        $("dropshiper_phone_number").attr("disable", false);
    } 
    else{
        $("#dropshiper_name").val("");
        $("#dropshiper_name").attr("disable", true);
        $("#dropshiper_phone_number").val("");
        $("#dropshiper_phone_number").attr("disable", true);
    }
});
$('#dropship').trigger('change');
```

how to fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

There may be a jQuery version problem with your code.

Please use the following code according to your jQuery version .
Use can check jQuery version in the included jQuery.js library.

```
            $('#dropship').click(function() {

                if ($(this).is(":checked")) {

                    /*For jquery version 1.6+ use following*/
                    $("#dropshiper_name").prop('disabled', false);
                    $("dropshiper_phone_number").prop("disabled", false);

                    /*For jquery version less than 1.6 use following*/
                    $("#dropshiper_name").attr('disabled','disabled');
                           $("dropshiper_phone_number").attr('disabled','disabled');

                } 
                else{

                    $("#dropshiper_name").val("");
                    $("#dropshiper_phone_number").val("");

                    /*For jquery version 1.6+ use following*/
                    $("#dropshiper_name").prop('disabled', true);
                    $("dropshiper_phone_number").prop("disabled", true);

                    /*For jquery version less than 1.6 use following*/  
                    $("#dropshiper_name").removeAttr('disabled');
                    $("#dropshiper_phone_number").removeAttr('disabled');

                }
            });
```

Try this . This will work for you.

Comment: can you please open the console and let me know what error is occurred. so that i can help you.

Comment: if i click my checkbox in console 

livesearch.js:101 Uncaught ReferenceError: n is not defined
    at HTMLHtmlElement.<anonymous> (livesearch.js:101)
    at HTMLHtmlElement.dispatch (jquery-1.7.1.min.js:3)
    at HTMLHtmlElement.i (jquery-1.7.1.min.js:3)
(anonymous) @ livesearch.js:101
dispatch @ jquery-1.7.1.min.js:3
i @ jquery-1.7.1.min.js:3

Comment: this error is not related to checkbox click there is some thing missing in your file.

Comment: how to fix it ? @sagar